# regex to block 2 patterns within n characters of each other

Tags: regex

What I want to do is create a singular regex that will find 'cat' and 'mouse' in a string if and only if there are between n and n2 chars between the two occurrences.

what I have tried (unsuccessfully) is this:

```
cat{1,12}?mouse
```

the goal is to get it to register in this sentence :

```
the cat and mouse played.
```

but not in this sentence:

```
the cat went out for lunch and on the way found the mouse
```

Comment: Any particular reason you want to use a regex? Why not find the index of each substring and compare them?

Comment: the reason i want to do it with regex is because it is being plugged into an existing banned phrases list that takes regex.

Comment: And, what can those characters be? Can they be, for example, character `\x00` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Where is the space in your regex??

```
cat[ ]{1,12}mouse
```

Not sure I understood your question correctly or not. If you want to consider any characters(other than newline) then use dot `.`

```
cat.{1,12}mouse
```

You can use word boundary around your words if you want to avoid picking words like `xcat`

```
\bcat\b[ ]{1,12}\bmouse\b
```

Comment: From the example it looks like the repeated bit should match any characters, not just spaces.

Comment: im not worried about the boundary around words so xcat would be fine for what im trying to do. And i dont understand your first question

Comment: @Michelle thanks. i was confused by the title. Updated the answer.

Comment: @Deslyxia I thought its to be space as you stated on your question's title.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do something like this?

```
cat.{1,12}mouse
```

That regex will match `cat` followed by 1-12 characters, followed by `mouse`.